# Passing List<String> in @RequestHeader Restapi

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I want to pass list of string in my controller via Request Header `@RequestHeader("list") final  List<String> listOfString`. Can this be used. How can I pass list of string in header via **Postman**?

`list={item1,item2,item3}`. This is not working while I want to test via Postman. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the header this way

[image]

In the headers tab, just add it with comas.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON Array Like This: ["data1","data2"]